# Data Storage for OOP in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am writing a Discord bot which has to store a lot of data by server, user, etc. The code is written with OOP, so I have several relatively complicated classes each storing smaller parts of the data.

When I need to make changes to the code, I obviously have to make the changes, then restart the code. Until now, I was storing the data in JSON files, but this has the following two problems:

1. As the classes grow more and more complicated, it is challenging/annoying to continuously update all the functions necessary to collapse all the data into a few JSON files.
2. Some of the classes need to reference each other (e.g. a User class references the servers it shares with the bot, a Server class references the users associated with the bot in the server).
3. It's somewhat inefficient, when I am using things like pandas dataframes, to be converting back and forth between different types.
4. It seems a bit inefficient to constantly be storing things in JSON files and dealing with the entire data every time for the smallest of queries.

For (2), I was using IDs & dictionaries to handle it relatively efficiently, but again, as the project grows it is hard to scale this with the storage.

Question: **What is the best way to store data when using OOP across runs in Python?**

EDIT: I am open to using external tools (if they are free) but would prefer sticking to local files (such as CSVs or JSONs) as much as possible.

Comment: Serialization libraries like https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html may be useful here.

Comment: @Marijn I read that pickle has security issues.

Comment: Also, can pickle handle cyclic references? For example, an object A has A.x = B and an object B has B.x = A. Would pickle be able to successfully serialize that?

Comment: The security issues are about running code from third parties in pickle files that you have downloaded from somewhere. If you only use it for your own data, especially during development, then that security risk is not an issue. For the cyclic references I'm not sure, but of course you can easily try that out with the two objects you gave as an example.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.